# installing cmfbibliography in plone

Tags: plone, bibliography

I'm using plone 4.2 and want to use product CMFBibliographyAT.  After running command buildout I get a lot of error messages regarding "'return' outside function".  When the command exits it prints:

```
*************** PICKED VERSIONS ****************
[versions]
Products.ATExtensions = 1.0
Products.CMFBibliographyAT = 1.1.2
bibliograph.core = 1.0.3
bibliograph.parsing = 1.0.1
bibliograph.rendering = 1.0.2
psycopg2 = 2.4.5
pyisbn = 0.6.0
*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
```

When  I go to zope interface and I can see these archetypes:

```
CMFBibliographyAT::LargeBibliographyFolder Uninstall
CMFBibliographyAT::DuplicatesBibliographyFolder Uninstall
CMFBibliographyAT::BibliographyFolder Uninstall
```

However, in plone when I try to add some content, there is no bibliography.

Any ideas why I can use this product?

Pedro

Comment: just to make sure: you installed the product in a plonesite via quickinstaller (or profile on creation)?

Comment: Now I known that those "return outside function" messages are normal because the python files are not ordinarily python modules.  I've run plone in foreground mode and I got an error in file `Products.ATExtensions-1.1a3/Products/ATExtensions/__init.py__` in instruction `validation.register(PartialUrlValidator('isPartialUrl'))`.  I've commented this instruction, rerun buildout and plonectl and voila!  Now I can enter references.

Comment: I've installed the product by specifying its name in the buildout.cfg file.  For product ATExtension I specified the path to the modified version (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

You did not actually get an error, your buildout completed fine.

When installing eggs, any `.py` files are compiled to `.pyc` cached byte-code files. However, Python Script files in Plone skin layers are a special form of Python that are treated as functions, and byte-compiling these always fails. *This is a side-effect and can be ignored*, see [Buildout and Syntax Errors](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/buildout.html#buildout-and-syntaxerrors).

The unified installer buildout configuration has been set up to inform you if buildout had to pick versions for you if not explicitly pinned to one.

The output you see tells you exactly what versions it picked, and you can re-use that output to set the pins yourself. Find the file `versions.cfg` and add the lines below the `[versions]` block in that file, below the same `[versions]` section you'll find in that file.

For more information on such version pinning and other buildout issues, see:

- [Brief version pinning tutorial](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/VersionPinning)
- [Buildout troubleshooting manual](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/buildout.html#buildout-troubleshooting)
- The [Unified Installer manual](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone)

If you do run into problems with these packages and get errors when you run your Zope instance, errors will be logged either to the console (when run in foreground mode) or the errors log. See [Add on product installation fails](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/diagnosing-third-party-product-installation-problems) for help with troubleshooting these.

Comment: I've tried different versions of product CMFBibliography and some of its versions.  I've only detected the error when I ran plone in foreground mode: it is more verbose about errors.

Comment: @user1556062: right, I didn't know you had an error in foreground mode, I do not get notified of updates to your question or of comments there.

Comment: I'm new to plone and python... After posting the question I kept reading the available documentation.  Regarding Products.ATExtension will contact the current maintainer about the patch I've made.

Comment: Excellent idea. Without seeing the traceback, it's hard to say what is wrong, but most likely you hit an incompatibility that is best solved by the package maintainers.